# Connect to SMB Server over command line

Tags: macos, smb

What is the equivalent to "Connect To Server" on the mac for the command line?

[image: Connect to Server]

I would like to automate the process rather than summon the dialog every time I need to connect to a server.

Comment: `mount_smbfs` with `mkdir`

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282778/14586) for how to mount it normally under `/Volumes/` using `osascript` on the command-line.

Comment: And also [this answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399035/14586) which details some of the differences between the various methods (`open smb:`, `osascript mount` and `mount`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to connect to remote server!
I am assuming you have server running on windows OS. Mac OS X includes the SMB protocol for networking with Windows computers; some Linux and Unix systems can also share files with this protocol as well. You can easily mount a shared SMB volume using the `mount` command. Steps to be followed as below

```
1) mkdir /temp
2) chmod 777
3) mount -t smbfs //username@ip/nameOfSharefolder /temp
```

After this you can browse to`/temp` directory and browse

You can also use ssh`ssh` or  `ftp` command to access the remote server but you need to run the ftp server in case of `ftp` command or remote access must be enable in case of `ssh`

Comment: Meanwhile SMB is the primary protocol on Macs, see [How to connect with File Sharing on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204445)

Comment: Why would they call the commnad mount_smbfs however the way you use it is "mount -f smbfs"? That seems confusing.

Comment: make sure the mount point `/temp` has appropriate permissions for the user executing the mount command